# Securely write a value to disk

Tags: c++, io, atomic, disk

I have a variable (of fixed size). I have a binary file on my disk on which that variable is saved. My C++ program needs to:

- Load the value of that variable from the disk
- Update the value of that variable on the disk

However, the system my program is running on is subject to power failure: at some point my system could be randomly disconnected from the power source therefore shutting down abruptly without any notice.

Therefore, I need the update operation to either be completed or not to happen at all on the disk. I tried figuring out on myself how to do such a thing, but one can never be sure what is the most correct and standard way to do such a thing. I need the solution to be cross-platform. So, for example, as far as I understood, the trick that involves writing the new value on a temporary file then renaming it will only work on POSIX compliant systems, on which the rename operation is atomic.

Is there a globally working solution? I am **not** interested in performance since that variable needs to be updated only once in a while.

Comment: Is the disk you are reading from and writing to using a journaling filesystem? Then just write and the file-system will make sure it's written.

Answer (score 6):

1. Open a new file in the same directory.
2. Write the new value of the variable to the file.
3. If you have some kind of synch operation (`sync`, `fsync`, `syncfs`, whatever) use it.
4. Close the file.
5. Rename the file you just wrote on top of the existing file.

While only POSIX guarantees that this will be atomic, every operating system you're likely to use will understand precisely what you want and, if the hardware is capable of it, give it to you.

Comment: Note that renaming a file "on top" of an existing file, while being documented to be an atomic operation (barring errors) *by POSIX*, the language standard itself only states that the behaviour is "implementation-defined". It's probably the closest you can get, anyhow.